# Ruby on Rails 2.3.8: Is there a way to make the destroy action for every controller only occur if a condition is met?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, authorization

Currently, in my app, I've discovered that if you intercept a packet about to perform a delete command, you can change the ID to any id, and that object will get deleted, regardless if it belong to the person who made it or not.

So, my question is, is there a way to somehow make a global modification to the way destroy / delete works such that the current_user must own the item about to be deleted (or whatever other condition, as many apps are a bit more complicated than simple user ownership)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a good idea to write global rule for destroy action. In the simplest way you just need to check access in your controllers:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :access, :only => [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  ...

  private
  def access
    my_object = MyObject.find(params[:id])
    unless logged_in? && my_object.user == current_user
      render :template => "/error/401.html.erb", :status => 401
    end
  end
end
```

Also you should look into [CanCan gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/cancan)

Comment: why is it not a good idea?
Maybe there is a way to specify exactly what controllers I want the rule to apply to. rather than copy pasting the same code everywhere (which is the worst thing in the world)

Comment: Then look into CanCan gem. It is easy with it to share the same functionality through controllers.

Comment: how would one pass the object to the filter? I just thought, your method could work if the before_filter method is in the application controller, rather than each controller. But I need a way to specify what object to use. can before filters take parameters?

Comment: You can put it into ApplicationController. And before_filter can work with all variables from headers (cookies, sessions etc).

Comment: http://www.antunkarlovac.com/blog/2008/07/15/passing-arguments-to-before_filter-in-a-rails-controller/

Comment: I've been testing what you have, and my object still keeps getting destroyed. =\

Comment: try instead of `render` -> `redirect_to :back`.

Comment: there is no back.. cause it's a functional test =(